# Linq to object dynamic query is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq

Wondering if it's possible to create a dynamic linq query using linq to objects.

I have a screen where a user can filter on multiple things.
I Need to build an in memory filtering NOT using a database

So lets suppose I have a list of customers in memory and I would like to filter based on some multiselection.

I thought a method that I could pass a predicate would do the trick ,but obviously not.

How can I do it?

eg

```
public class Biz
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllByName(string name)
    {
        return Repository.Find(x=> x.Name == name);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private List<Customer> internalCustomerList = GetAllCustomers();

    public IEnumerable<Customer> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        //How do I make below work in linq to object
        return  internalCustomerList.Where(predicate);//error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do your `Find` method returns `Expression<Func, bool>>` and not `IEnumerable<Customer>`?

Comment: edited to return Ienumerable<Customer>

Comment: What error are you getting?  It is ok to do something similar to what you are doing above, so I am curious what the error was.

Comment: @AdamJones I am getting "The type arguments for method "IEnumerable<T>System.Linq.Enumerable.Where(this bla...)cannot be inferred from usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
public class Biz
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllByName(string name)
    {
        return Repository.Find(x=>x.Name == name);
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private List<Customer> internalCustomerList = GetAllCustomers();

    public static IEnumerable<Customer> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return internalCustomerList.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Please note that `List<T>` does not have an overload for `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Only `IQueryable<T>` has. See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: .Thanks that works.Why I can do public IEnumerable<Customer> Find(Func<Customer, bool> predicate) { return _internalCustomerList.Where(predicate); } but gives me an error if I do public IEnumerable<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate) { return internalCustomerList.Where(predicate); }.I need some casting but not sure how

Comment: I think what you need is `public static IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(Func<T,bool> predicate)` (note the generic <T> on the Find method.  That should allow you to return `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

An alternate approach would be to pass a string filter rather than a predicate. The [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) makes this possible.

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Find(string filter)
{
    //filter would be something like "Age >= 20"
    return internalCustomerList.Where(filter);
}
```

Comment: +1 I use this library in conjunction with JQGrid, very powerfull

Answer (score 1):

`IEnumerable<T>` only has extension methods with delegates, aka `.Where(Func<T, bool> predicate)`

Use `.AsQueryable()` to get a `IQueryable<T>` which supports `.Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>>)`

Comment: Do you have an example how I can implement AsQueryable thanks

Comment: `.AsQueryable()` is a standard extension method on all `IEnumerable` which uses Linq to Objects.  There is no need to implement anything. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. You need to use a `compile` method to convert your expression to the callable method. I've not tested the code, but it should be very close to the following:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Find(Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate)
{
    return  internalCustomerList.Where(predicate.compile());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .Got an error "Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration" googled but cannot seem to work it out

Comment: I've tried and corrected my code. Things are even simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

I use a predicate builder class for my LINQ queries:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

code sample:

```
private static IQueryable<AppointmentDTO> FilterAppointmentData(IEnumerable<AppointmentDTO> data, AppointmentSearchDTO searchData)
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<AppointmentDTO>();
            if (searchData.Status != null)
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Status.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(searchData.Status)));
            if (searchData.LastName != null)
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchData.LastName.ToLower()));
            if (searchData.File != null)
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.File.ToLower().Contains(searchData.File.ToLower()));
            if (searchData.Doctor != null)
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Doctor.ToLower().Contains(searchData.Doctor.ToLower()));
            return data.AsQueryable().Where(predicate);
        }
```

Got it from here:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Cheers!